# Curious Internal Name Unicode Encoding Behavior

Tags: 2010

I found out that, when I create fields programmatically with rather small internal names, the very first character of that internal name will get encoded.

For example: BN67 becomes `%5Fx0042%5FN67` or `_x0042_N67`. The character B has been encoded. **Why does SharePoint do this?**

So far, longer field names have not produced similar behavior.

Comment: FYI, that isn't ASCII. 'x0042' is Unicode (http://www.marathon-studios.com/unicode/U0042/Latin_Capital_Letter_B).

Comment: Check out this SO post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1600647/internal-name-encoding-in-sharepoint Doesn't answer why this happens, but it gives you a method to decode the string for comparisons.